# How to generate a file for download in a Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to generate a CSV file as the result of some user interactions and then prompt the user to download it. How can I do that?

I don't think it's possible in straight JS, but perhaps Chrome gives me some elevated privileges?

Comment: I've done this in ASP.NET. What technologies are you using?

Comment: @Jon: Chrome extensions are written in JS... don't think I have any other options.

Answer (score 5):

You can now use HTML5 [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) to download a file. It is still in development, but you can use a BlobBuilder and redirect your use to download that file:

```
var bb = new BlobBuilder();
bb.append(csvContents);
var blob = bb.getBlob(); 
location.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

For more information regarding the File API, HTML5Rocks has a great tutorial:

http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: Yes, in Chrome 10 they changed it to be "window.webkitURL.createObjectURL". I edited my answer to reflect that. The only problem with this approach (will get solved soon) is that you cannot control the filename. Try it out in your inspector.

Comment: "Not allowed to load local resource: blob:null/6b2c341a-ad40-48b2-9755-1b7134832d39". I can copy that into my address bar and download the file, but why won't Chrome allow it?

Comment: For development, try adding the following command line argument to Chrome: `--allow-file-access-from-files`

Comment: @Mohammed: Yeah, that works. Very close to being usable... but I think I need a save-as dialog.

Comment: At this time, you can't have a save as dialog. Perhaps you can imitate it and ask the user to check their download directory.

Answer (score 5):

I needed to do exactly the same recently - generating file and enforcing its download in Chrome extension. Here you are a code snippet doing that, using ES6 and the recommended methods:

```
let docContent = ... /* your content */;
let doc = URL.createObjectURL( new Blob([docContent], {type: 'application/octet-binary'}) );
chrome.downloads.download({ url: doc, filename: filename, conflictAction: 'overwrite', saveAs: true });
```

You also have to declare a proper privilege in `manifest.json`:

```
"permissions" : ["downloads"]
```

Comment: It looks like this no longer works in manifest v3 because the service worker (formerly background page) can't use `URL.createObjectURL`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68137730/2336725

Answer (score 1):

Chrome doesn't provide any help with this, but I think you should be able to trigger a file save dialog using [downloadify](http://pixelgraphics.us/downloadify/test.html) js library which uses a flash component behind the scenes.

Comment: Seems to crash Firefox for me when I try the demo. Chrome doesn't crash though...so, I guess I can live with that.