# Browser - file writer extension?

Tags: javascript, browser, firefox-addon, google-chrome-extension

Is there any chrome or firefox extension that allows javascript to create write files in client's PC?

Comment: Writing files to a clients machine (apart from cookies) is generally considered a major security issue. of course hackers never seem to have much trouble doing it...

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771758/how-to-generate-a-file-for-download-in-a-google-chrome-extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to do?

HTML5 has a [File API](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/).  This is the best solution because it allows selection of the file to be wholly under user control.

If you must, you can make your own [NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI) plugin which exposes itself to scripting (aka [NPRuntime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI#NPRuntime)) and performs native local file operations on behalf of Javascript in the page.  Or, in IE, `new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` may yield a [`FileSystemObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50.aspx) (depending on ActiveX settings).  But please don't.

Comment: Great answer, I recommend the html5rocks tutorials for File API http://www.html5rocks.com/features/file

Answer (score 1):

```
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/filelocal;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
file.initWithPath("Pathforfile");

file.create(Components.interfaces.nsIFile.NORMAL_FILE_TYPE, 420 );
var outputStream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"].createInstance( Components.interfaces.nsIFileOutputStream );
outputStream.init( file, 0x04 | 0x08 | 0x20, 420, 0 );
var output="Texttowriteinfile";                                     
var result = outputStream.write( output, output.length );
outputStream.close();
```