# how to read/write file from hard disk using firefox addon?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

Is it possible to develop a Firefox addon that can read/write a file from hard disk? What code should I use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824017/browser-file-writer-extension/4825034#4825034

Comment: Also: http://simon-jung.blogspot.com/2007/10/firefox-extension-file-io.html

Answer (score 2):

it's just copy (and combination ) of code in links @Hypnos and @ephemient provided:

```
const {Cc,Ci} = require("chrome");

//create proper path for file
var theFile = 'd:\\q.txt';
//create component for file writing
var file = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsILocalFile);
file.initWithPath( theFile );
if(file.exists() == false) //check to see if file exists
{
    file.create( Ci.nsIFile.NORMAL_FILE_TYPE, 420);
}
var foStream = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/file-output-stream;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIFileOutputStream);
// use 0x02 | 0x10 to open file for appending.
//foStream.init(file, 0x02 | 0x10, 0666, 0);
foStream.init(file, 0x02 | 0x08 | 0x20, 0666, 0); 

// if you are sure there will never ever be any non-ascii text in data you can
// also call foStream.write(data, data.length) directly
var converter = Cc["@mozilla.org/intl/converter-output-stream;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIConverterOutputStream);
converter.init(foStream,"UTF-8", 0, 0);
converter.writeString('Hi, This is Death. Who are you?');
converter.close(); // this closes foStream
```

Comment: works perfectly thank you so much :)
just for reference: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/nsprpub/pr/include/prio.h#569