# Firefox open file from add-on instead of local path

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk

I am creating Firefox add-on which run a specific `.bat` file.

This is code I used.

`main.js`

```
const {Components, Cc, Ci,Cu} = require("chrome");

var file = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIFile);
file.initWithPath("C:\\Users\\Madhawa.se\\Desktop\\snap\\shoot.bat"); // i want to open this bat from xpi .for example from data directory
var args="this is an argument  ";
var process = Cc["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIProcess);
process.init(file);
process.run(false, args, args.length);
```

It works fine but I would like to open `shoot.bat` file from inside of add-on  so I can easily distribute add-on as a single `xpi`.

How can I open this bat file from add-on for example I can put `shoot.bat` file inside of `data directory` of my Firefox add-on, but how can I open it ? isn't it possible? is there any better way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it is reasonably easy to read data from within your add-on XPI, you cannot create processes that way. Windows in general, and the windows executable loader in particular, do not know how to read `.xpi`.

Executing a batch file, or it's contents, might be achieved by either writing the batch file somewhere on the disk prior to execution, or assembling a [`cmd /K`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713960/cmd-exe-k-switch) compatible argument string with the contents of that batch file

Reading the batch file in the first place can be achieved e.g. by using the [`request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request) module together with a `data.url()`.

```
const {Request} = require("sdk/request");
const {data} = require("sdk/self");

Request({url: data.url("shoot.bat"), onComplete: function(response) {
  var batch = response.text;
  // ...
}});
```

Of course, it might be easier just to put the contents of the batch file in the Javascript source itself to avoid the `Request` stuff altogether.

Now, you can either write the batch file contents to a file, e.g. using [`io/file`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/io_file) and/or [`OS.File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/OSFile.jsm/OS.File_for_the_main_thread) (the latter is preferred at the moment, mainly because `io/file` is not async), and execute that.

Or you can properly format the contents to be used with `cmd /K`.

Comment: so tnx .how ever  can i pass arguments using  this method `data.url("shoot.bat")`? arguments are important i my  case

Comment: i used your code but it seems  not work.it doesn't run that bat.any idea

Comment: @nmaier: Good idea, but why not use [data.load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/self#data.load(name))? Like this: `const {data} = require("sdk/self"); var contentOfBatFile = data.load("shoot.bat")`

Comment: @Ruud Yeah, that would work too (I did say e.g. ;), but I personally favor async loading and `data.load` is sync.

Comment: @FastSnail Use nmaier's code sample to retrieve the content of the batch file (as a string), then write that content to a file on the local hard drive (preferably in the temp folder) as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983175/how-to-read-write-file-from-hard-disk-using-firefox-addon). From there, follow your original approach. Though from a security point of view, I prefer nmaier's last suggestion: execute `cmd.exe` with parameter `/K "foo"` where _foo_ is the content of the batch file (use `;` or `&` to make it a one-liner). Use search & replace to inject parameters.

Comment: @Ruud tnxi will try that .