# save base64 as an image in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension which uses the `captureVisibleTab` method and in it's callback there is a base64 encoded string of the image. How to save the image to the local file system or prompt a browser save as dialog.

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, function(img) {
  img.replace('image/png', 'image/octet-stream');
});
```

I did, base64 encoded string as an octet stream, but chrome extensions have restrictions on it. I also read about, NPAPI plugin but I was not able to make much progress there.

Comment: You should probably try a File API - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771758/how-to-generate-a-file-for-download-in-a-google-chrome-extension