# TypeError: Error URL.createObjectURL() not a function

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to create a chrome extension that downloads a file with text inside. Some examples for doing this I've seen need to create a URL to pass to

`chrome.downloads.download({ url: url, filename: fileName, conflictAction: 'overwrite', saveAs: false });`

However, when I try to use URL.createUrlObject(), I get a type error

var blob = new Blob([textFile], {type: 'application/octet-binary'});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

I am using manifest v3

Comment: createObjectURL is not allowed in a service worker so just use a `data` URL e.g. 'data:text/plain,' + textFile.replace(/#/g, '%23')

Comment: https://crbug.com/1224027

Comment: @wOxxOm, i'm new to js and chrome extension development, i'm having the same issue and couldn't figure out how to fix it. tried to create data uri using chrome.window.btoa, which is also throwing error. could you please post the solution here as an answer?

Comment: Use `btoa` instead of `chrome.window.btoa`. Ask a new question for further assistance if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

```js
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.type === "saveCSV") {
    // for utf8 bom 
    const data = '\uFEFF' + request.data;
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8" });

    // use BlobReader object to read Blob data
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = () => {
      const buffer = reader.result;
      const blobUrl = `data:${blob.type};base64,${btoa(new Uint8Array(buffer).reduce((data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte), ''))}`;
      chrome.downloads.download({
        url: blobUrl,
        filename: request.filename,
        saveAs: true,
        conflictAction: "uniquify"
      }, () => {
        sendResponse({ success: true });
      });
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
    return true;
  }
});
```

hope this can help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

a mi me funciono de esta manera:

```
 const binary = atob(codigoBase64);

        const blob = new Blob([binary], { type: "application/pdf" });
        
        const dataURL = `data:${blob.type};base64,${btoa(binary)}`;

        chrome.downloads.download({
            url: dataURL,
            filename: `${nombreArchivo}`,
            saveAs: true, 
        });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).